# Set default key in gpg for signing

Tags: encryption, gpg, signature

I have created multiple keys using gpg.

Whenever I try to sign any file, gpg automatically uses the first one I have created. How to set default key for signing in gpg. I don't want to delete/revoke the other one yet.

Otherwise, how can I change my default keys for signing?

Answer (score 57):

To choose a default key without having to specify `--default-key` on the command-line every time, create a configuration file (if it doesn't already exist), `~/.gnupg/gpg.conf`, and add a line containing

```
default-key <key-fpr>
```

replacing `<key-fpr>` with the id or fingerprint of the key you want to use by default.

Comment: but how do i get the '<key-fpr>' ? In what format? When I do 'gpg -K' it prints long ID with spaces.

Comment: @400 take the “Key fingerprint” line from `gpg -K` and use the value after the = sign; you can include the spaces, so copy-paste works, you don’t even need quotes.

Comment: your output must be different. I see 4 lines: `1) sec rsa4096 ...`, `2) what I think is the key id, ie: ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff`, but there is no `=` sign, `3) my name and email`, `4) ssb rsa4096 ...`

Comment: @400 weird, I see a “Key fingerprint” line on all the platforms I’ve checked this on. Anyway, that long value is probably your fingerprint, not your key id, and you can use that as the `default-key` value. (Key ids are the values given with `rsa4096` etc.)

Comment: I see the same output as @400theCat on Debian, gpg 2.2.27. The long value is the fingerprint, the last 16 chars of that is the long key id, and the last 8 chars is the short key id. You can also get the long key ids with `gpg --list-signatures` or the short key ids with `gpg --list-signatures --keyid-format short`. Anyway, the `default-key` option works with any of those options (fingerprint, long id, or short id).

Answer (score 2):

These steps are for EVERY GPG signing.  That is, you don’t want to use the tedious `—default-key` on the CLI anymore.

List your signatures:

```
gpg —list-signatures
```

Select your key to be that default.
Then set the key default:

```
echo ‘default-key:0:”xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx’ | gpgconf —change-options gpg
```

please note that there is only ONE double-quote, which signifies that a text string is about to begin.  Also that there is a pair of single-quote surround the entire echo statement.

there are three values separated by two colon symbols.

- First is the configuration keyword option “default-key”
- Second is pretty much always ‘0’, which means no special flag bit set.  ‘16’ means to delete the key from its configuration file.  More on [special flags](https://www.gnupg.org/documentation/manuals/gnupg/Changing-options.html)

Also for `gpgconf`, the `—change-options` requires an argument.  That argument indicates a component name that helps chooses which configuration file to make the change with.  Component names used are commonly `gpg` for the `~/.gnupg/gpg.conf` file and `gpg-agent` for `~/.gnupg/gpg-agent.conf` file. More on component names [here](https://www.gnupg.org/documentation/manuals/gnupg/Listing-components.html#Listing-components).

Once the setting of default key is done, if you want to use a different key of yours, use the `—local-user <your name>` on the `gpg` command line just for that message.   Or the easier `-u <your name>` option instead.

Note that `-u` or `--local-user` overrides this `—default-key`  at command line or in `gpg.conf` setting.